# How to call public functions dynamically at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, function, dynamic, call

I want to call the functions by their name at run time like

```
string srFunctionName="MyFunction";
```

So with using this variable i want to call function named as "MyFunction". How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx):

```
string strFunctionName = "MyFunction";

// get the type containing the method
Type t = Type.GetType("Foo.Bar.SomeTypeContainingYourFunction");

// you will need an instance of the type if the method you are
// trying to invoke is not static. If it is static you could leave that null
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

// the arguments that your method expects
new object[] arguments = new object[] { 1, "foo", false };

// invoke the method
object result = t.InvokeMember(
    strFunctionName, 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
    null, 
    instance, 
    arguments
);
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's a full example with real functions:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public class SomeTypeContainingYourFunction
    {
        public string MyFunction(int foo, string bar, bool baz)
        {
            return string.Format("foo: {0}, bar: {1}, baz: {2}", foo, bar, baz);
        }
    }
}

namespace Bazinga
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var strFunctionName = "MyFunction";
            var t = Type.GetType("Foo.Bar.SomeTypeContainingYourFunction");
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            var arguments = new object[] { 1, "foo", false };
            var result = t.InvokeMember(
                strFunctionName, 
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                null, 
                instance, 
                arguments
            );
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. Can you give a full example including some basic real functions. This is really confusing. I will also pass HtmlDocument varible as a parameter to the function. HtmlDocument is object of htmlagilitypack.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, sure, I have included a full example. Please checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to close the a `form`

```
object instance = form;
Type myType = form.GetType();

myType.InvokeMember("Close", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to create an object of a class and then call a function using that object.

```
    object Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // t is type
    MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod(srFunctionName); 
    if (mi != null)
            mi.Invoke(Instance, args);
    else
           logError();
```